# Facebook javascript upon login a called function runs twice but should only run once

Tags: javascript, facebook, function

I am using the code from:

http://thinkdiff.net/demo/newfbconnect1/jssdkouth2.html

to integrate Facebook into my app, I have the following functions:

```
function login(response, info){
    if (response.authResponse) {
        showLoader(true);
        var accessToken                                 =   response.authResponse.accessToken;      

        fqlQuery();

        userInfo.innerHTML                             = 'Logged in';
        document.getElementById("fb-auth").setAttribute("class", "fb_logout");
        showLoader(false);
        document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";
    }
}


function fqlQuery(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/
        var query       =  FB.Data.query('select email from user where uid={0}', response.id);      
            alert("test");

    });
};
```

The problem I have is when I login the function fqlquery runs, except that it runs twice how can I prevent this? (ie test popups on screen twice).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue of this code running twice is most likely due to including multiple versions of the SDK on your page; e.g. including more than one like button, including a social plugin and initializing an application, etc.

You can either address the issue of the SDK initializing more than once, or you can add a mutual exclusion check in your fqlQuery function that prevents it from running more than once:

```
function login(response, info){
    if (response.authResponse) {
        showLoader(true);
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;      

        fqlQuery();

        userInfo.innerHTML                             = 'Logged in';
        document.getElementById("fb-auth").setAttribute("class", "fb_logout");
        showLoader(false);
        document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";
    }
}
var hasRun = false;
function fqlQuery(){
    if (hasRun === false) {
        hasRun = true;
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/
            var query =  FB.Data.query('select email from user where uid={0}', response.id);      
            alert("test");
    }
});
```

};